# ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to install an Odoo 8 Module on Odoo 9. I am getting ParseError: "Invalid view definition. I tried reading the documentation but I am only learning and finding it hard to follow

**Error I am getting**

```
File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 1281, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError('\n'.join(errors))
ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Error details:
Element '<xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']">' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `select_cashier_module_index index`
[view_id: 699, xml_id: n/a, model: n/a, parent_id: 636]
None" while parsing None:7, near
<data name="select_cashier_module_index index" inherit_id="point_of_sale.index">
            <xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']" position="after">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/css/pos.css"/>
            </xpath>

        </data>
```

**Here is the templates.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

        <template id="index" name="select_cashier_module_index index"
                  inherit_id="point_of_sale.index">
            <xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']" position="after">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/css/pos.css"/>
            </xpath>

        </template>

        <template id="assets_backend" name="select_cashier_module assets"
                  inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/js/db.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/js/models.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/js/screens.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/js/widgets.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/js/main.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as `Odoo-9` I looked into Odoo 9 code to solve your issue.

I believe the `point_of_sale.index` that you set to inherit from is [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/point_of_sale/views/templates.xml) which does not have any `<link>` with `id = "pos-stylesheet"`.

It is however in the POS assets template [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/point_of_sale/views/point_of_sale.xml), so what you need to do is to change your code to inherit from `point_of_sale.assets` instead of `point_of_sale.index`.

Therefore:

```
<template id="index" name="select_cashier_module_index index"
              inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
    <xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']" position="after">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_select_cashier/static/src/css/pos.css"/>
    </xpath>

</template>
```

Also, make sure that in your `__openerp__.py` you already listed `point_of_sale` as one of your dependencies.

Comment: After changing the point_of_sale.index to point_of_sale.assets I get Raise NotFound() Not found 404. I cant load Odoo at all. I created another database and tried it again with no other modules only Point of sale but I get the same error.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? A 404 error is a error on the front end that is usually as simple as a bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

this is a correct code :-

```
<template id="assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/lib/js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/multiprint.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/splitbill.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/printbill.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/floors.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_restaurant/static/src/js/notes.js"></script>
      </xpath>
      <xpath expr="//link[@id='pos-stylesheet']" position="after">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pos_restaurant/static/src/css/restaurant.css" />
      </xpath>
    </template>
```

so in your manifest file try to add

```
 'depends': ['point_of_sale'],
```